# Flutter project couldn't resolve ':classpath'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to run an app but I encounter this;

> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.13/google-services-4.3.13.pom
>   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.13/google-services-4.3.13.pom
>   Required by:
>   project :

I have put google-services.json in app folders,
I have tried:

- gradlew --scan : I got and exception.

> Gradle version: 7.4
> Plugin version: 3.8.1
> Request URL: https://scans-in.gradle.com/scans/publish/gradle/3.8.1/token
> Request ID: 518f437c-3ef8-481c-8c00-a1d76826c7a8
> Exception: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Request blocked by Privoxy"

I tried using VPN and still did not work

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling android build tools

and

add this line `"systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*|localhost"`in gradle.properties